# Will IE, Firefox, and Chrome be unicode domain compatible

Tags: browser, unicode, domain-name

Since there will soon be [Hebrew domain names](http://www.foxnews.com/story/0,2933,570470,00.html), I'm wondering if the major browsers already have support for this built in, or whether we'll have to wait for a future release to visit our favorite Hebrew sites, such as יואלעלתוכנה.com?

Comment: Markdown really doesn't deal with Hebrew well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) has been around for quite a while, I guess that all browser already support this.

For example: if your browser is able to deal with [www.ίδρυματεχνολογίασέρευνασ.gr](http://www.%CE%AF%CE%B4%CF%81%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%AF%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B5%CF%85%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%83.gr/) (which will translate to [www.xn--ixadahbbkgke5djpgxb1al0bfgtp0b.gr](http://www.xn--ixadahbbkgke5djpgxb1al0bfgtp0b.gr/)) then it should also be able to deal with Hebrew domain names.

Comment: Markdown indeed sucks dead bunnies when it comes to utf-8 domains.

Comment: Hebrew being slightly more complex than www.ίδρυματεχνολογίασέρευνασ.gr, given the right-to-left writing...

Comment: Good point. Hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

IE uses most of the same libraries as Windows itself, which has been fully unicode compatible since Windows NT.

Chrome is a new project, by browser standards, so it would be very short sighted if it wasn't.

Firefox is the only fully open source mainstream browser, so if it isn't compatible yet, it soon will be.

Comment: It's not about Unicode per se. IDN needs translation from Unicode to punycode, which is a browser issue. (But indeed, most browsers already support that.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [an article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/h2g2/A54511986) about this a while ago. Extract:

> **Safari** decided to disable Cherokee,
>   Cyrillic, and Greek scripts by
>   default. These three scripts all have
>   many Latin lookalike characters. This
>   is well and good if you have a
>   majority English-speaking audience,
>   but not ideal for the rest of the
>   world. And it certainly doesn't solve
>   all the problems. Latin characters
>   with unusual diacritics will still
>   work, and some fonts leave out some of
>   these diacritics, so that l and
>   l-cedila may well look identical.
>
> **Opera**, and later **Firefox**, took the
>   position that this was a register
>   issue: Internet registers should not
>   allocate domains such as
>   www.xn--pypal-4ve.com in the first
>   place. These browser manufacturers
>   maintain a whitelist of 'well behaved'
>   registrars, who don't allow spoofing
>   domains in their registry. For
>   example, it would be impossible to
>   register www.xn--pypal-4ve.info,
>   because the .info registrar wouldn't
>   allow it. Opera's whitelist of TLDs
>   is built into the browser. Firefox's
>   list is on display. It's worth noting
>   that the most popular registrar, .com,
>   allocates domains strictly on a
>   first-come-first-served basis, with no
>   checks at all. Therefore, IDNs in .com
>   will not work in Opera or Firefox.
>
> Google's new **Chrome** browser has IDNAs
>   turned off by default.
>
> **Internet Explorer** is, of course, more
>   integrated with the operating system
>   than most browsers are, so it checks
>   what language supports are configured
>   within Windows. If the script in the
>   IDN is part of the user's configured
>   accept language, the name will display
>   as an IDNA. Otherwise, the punycode
>   will be shown. However, when scripts
>   are mixed (Cyrillic and Latin in the
>   same label, for example), the punycode
>   will be shown, even if Cyrillic (in
>   our example) is usually accepted. Some
>   scripts which look nothing like Latin
>   are allowed to mix, as these don't
>   present a threat.